# Machine a/c unable to connect to sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

The system here uses the client side machine account i.e. domain\machinename$ to connect to a SQL Server database hosted on a server.

Due to updgrades a new machine had to be created, was given same name, ip, dns etc as previous machine but now is unable to login into the database, returning a generic "Login failed for user" exception message.

Am I right in thinking that although the new machine has same name etc as old machine that the previously granted rights to the machinename$ a/c need to be re-granted by removing previous a/c & roles from the db and re-adding them?

If Yes, what would be going on "under the hood" in SQL Server that would require this?

Comment: Is it the client machine that was upgraded or the Server itself?

Comment: It was the client machine that was upgraded, database server is unchanged

Comment: New pc has different SID, thereby all domain access rights have to be updated - starting from domain controller.